# SQL insert multiple rows with one static value, one variable ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a database that has the following setup:

```
SiteSecurityID | SiteID | LoginName
---------------+--------+-----------
Auto Gen #       Number   Username
```

Now, we have 35 SiteID's and every user needs access to each one. I cannot get any query I've tried to do this successfully.

I can do it one by one using this method, but there has to be an easier way...

```
INSERT INTO SiteSecurity (SiteID, LoginName) 
VALUES ('1', 'user1'), ('2', 'user1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate all the rows using a `cross join`, assuming you have tables for sites and users:

```
INSERT INTO SiteSecurity (SiteID, LoginName)
    SELECT s.SiteId, u.UserName
    FROM Sites s CROSS JOIN
         users u;
```

If you don't you can still generate them on the fly.  Table constructors vary by database, but this gives the approach:

```
INSERT INTO SiteSecurity (SiteID, LoginName)
    SELECT s.SiteId, u.UserName
    FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), . . . ) s(SiteID) CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES ('user1'),  ('user2'), . . . ) u(UserName);
```

EDIT:

If you have existing data, you can filter out duplicates before inserting:

```
INSERT INTO SiteSecurity (SiteID, LoginName)
    SELECT s.SiteId, u.UserName
    FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), . . . ) s(SiteID) CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES ('user1'),  ('user2'), . . . ) u(UserName) LEFT JOIN
         SiteSecurity ss
         ON ss.SiteId = s.SiteId AND ss.LoginName = u.UserName
    WHERE ss.SiteId IS NULL;
```

Comment: This program for these tables is an all over nightmare. We are merging our users with another set, so there is existing data there.

Comment: The second solution works! Thank you so much Gordon!

Comment: More for the OP's benefit: It is likely beneficial to left join to the SiteSecurity table and add a SiteSecurity.SiteID IS NULL to the WHERE to ensure you don't insert duplicates